# $\int_Xfd\mu < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n\in\omega}2^{n}\mu\{f(x)\geq 2^n\}<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:(X,S,\mu)\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$ measure with $\mu$ a finite measure. Proof
$\int_Xfd\mu < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n\in\omega}2^{n}\mu\{x\in X:f(x)\geq 2^n\}<\infty$.
My attempt for the $\Longrightarrow)$ was define $A_n=\{x\in X : f(x)\geq 2^{n}\}$ and $g_n=\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n2^i\chi_{A_i}}{n+1}$ by induction $g_n\leq f$ for all $n\in \omega$ and clearly $g_n$ is simple.
Now we have a secuence of integrals $\{\int_X g_n\text{d}\mu\}_{n\in \omega}$ monotonous and bounded by $\int_Xfd\mu$, then $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}} \dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n2^i\mu(A_i)}{n+1}=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\int_X g_n\text{d}\mu < \infty}$. I think i'm close, cause $\sum_{i=0}^n2^i\mu(A_i)$ is the thing i want to proof is convergent.
Any help or advice, please

Comment: It should be $\mu\{ x \in X \colon 2^{n+1} > f(x) \ge 2^n\}$ instead in your sum

Comment: I`m asking my teacher, now its very clearly with that. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n \geq 0} 2^n \mu(A_n \setminus A_{n+1}) = \mu(A_0) + \sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{n-1} \mu(A_n).$